# Pandas concat changes Int to Object (no null values)

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a bunch of queries to SQL via pandas (read_sql_query) and want to combine all the resulted dataframes into one. The results from each query have the appropriate dtypes. There are no null values but anyway the concatenation changes all my int columns to object.

```
event_list_frames = []
for event_id in events[id]:
        event_list_frames.append(get_previous_events(event_id))
all_previous_events = pd.concat(event_list_frames)
```

All results from the get_previous_events method have the following type:

```
date             datetime64[ns]
event_id                  int64
event_category            int64
size_of_x                 float_64
size_of_y                 float_64
dtype: object
```

After the concation we get the following dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6240 entries, 1156 to 648
Data columns (total 14 columns):
date             6240 non-null datetime64[ns]
event_id         6240 non-null object
event_category   6240 non-null object
size_of_x        6240 non-null float64
size_of_y        6240 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(2)
```

As you can see all columns have exactly 6240 non-null entries, but why are my int columns converted to object? How to avoid this?

Comment: what does `[df['event_id'].dtypes for df in event_list_frames if df['event_id'].dtypes == 'object']` return? Do the same for `event_category`

Comment: event_id :  `[dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O')]`

event_category: `[dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O'), dtype('O')]`

Comment: There is the problem...`event_id` and `event_category` is an object in 14 DataFrames in `event_list_frames`

Comment: Thanks that led me to the solution. There were just empty dataframes where those columns where of object type. Just filtering in the loop empty dataframes solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear...Good luck.